# Number of elements of array less than each element of cutoff array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a numpy array of strictly increasing "cutoff" values of length `m`, and a pandas series of values (thought the index isn't important and this could be cast to a numpy array) of values of length `n`. 
I need to come up with an efficient way of spitting out a length `m` vector of counts of the number of elements in the pandas series less than the jth element of the "cutoff" array.

I could do this via a list iterator:

```
output = array([(pan_series < cutoff_val).sum() for cutoff_val in cutoff_ar])
```

but I was wondering if there were any way to do this that leveraged more of numpy's magic speed, as I have to do this quite a few times inside multiple loops and it keeps crasshing my computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
In [36]: a = np.random.random(20)

In [37]: a
Out[37]: 
array([ 0.68574307,  0.15743428,  0.68006876,  0.63572484,  0.26279663,
        0.14346269,  0.56267286,  0.47250091,  0.91168387,  0.98915746,
        0.22174062,  0.11930722,  0.30848231,  0.1550406 ,  0.60717858,
        0.23805205,  0.57718675,  0.78075297,  0.17083826,  0.87301963])

In [38]: b = np.array((0.3,0.7))

In [39]: np.sum(a[:,None]<b[None,:], axis=0)
Out[39]: array([ 8, 16])

In [40]: np.sum(a[:,None]<b, axis=0) # b's new axis above is unnecessary...
Out[40]: array([ 8, 16])

In [41]: (a[:,None]<b).sum(axis=0)   # even simpler
Out[41]: array([ 8, 16])
```

Timings are always well received (for a longish, 2E6 elements array)

```
In [47]: a = np.random.random(2000000)

In [48]: %timeit (a[:,None]<b).sum(axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 78.2 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a, b, 'right',sorter=a.argsort())
1 loop, best of 3: 448 ms per loop
```

For a smaller array

```
In [50]: a = np.random.random(2000)

In [51]: %timeit (a[:,None]<b).sum(axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 89 µs per loop

In [52]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a, b, 'right',sorter=a.argsort())
The slowest run took 4.86 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 141 µs per loop
```

---

*Edit*

Divakar says that things may be different for lenghty `b`s, let's see

```
In [71]: a = np.random.random(2000)

In [72]: b =np.random.random(200)

In [73]: %timeit (a[:,None]<b).sum(axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a, b, 'right',sorter=a.argsort())
10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop
```

quite different indeed! Thank you for prompting my curiosity.

Probably the OP should test for his use case, very long sample with respect to cutoff sequences or not? and where there is a balance?

---

*Edit #2*

I made a blooper in my timings, I forgot the `axis=0` argument to `.sum()`...

I've edited the timings with the corrected statement and, of course, the corrected timing. My apologies.

Comment: I love broadcasting too! But, you gotta try out with a bigger `b` than with just 2 elements I think.

Comment: @Divakar You're right! I've made an amendment  to my post.

Comment: Yeah something like `(pan_series[:,None]<cutoff_ar).sum(0)` to go along with the variable names from the question I guess.

Comment: Broadcasting can be applied also to tabular data, say `a.shape -> (200, 50)` with `(a[:,:,None]<b).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for some `NumPy magic` -

```
# Convert to numpy array for some "magic"
pan_series_arr = np.array(pan_series)

# Let the magic begin!
sortidx = pan_series_arr.argsort()
out = np.searchsorted(pan_series_arr,cutoff_ar,'right',sorter=sortidx)
```

**Explanation**

You are performing `[(pan_series < cutoff_val).sum() for cutoff_val in cutoff_ar]` i.e. for each
element in `cutoff_ar`, we are counting the number of `pan_series` elements that are lesser than it. Now with `np.searchsorted`, we are looking for `cutoff_ar`  to be put in a sorted `pan_series_arr` and get the indices of such positions compared to whom the current element in `cutoff_ar` is at `'right'` position . These indices essentially represent the number of `pan_series` elements below the current `cutoff_ar` element, thus giving us our desired output.

**Sample run**

```
 In [302]: cutoff_ar
Out[302]: array([ 1,  3,  9, 44, 63, 90])

In [303]: pan_series_arr
Out[303]: array([ 2,  8, 69, 55, 97])

In [304]: [(pan_series_arr < cutoff_val).sum() for cutoff_val in cutoff_ar]
Out[304]: [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

In [305]: sortidx = pan_series_arr.argsort()
     ...: out = np.searchsorted(pan_series_arr,cutoff_ar,'right',sorter=sortidx)
     ...: 

In [306]: out
Out[306]: array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: This is great, and I'm now using searchsorted in a number of times in my code. However, for the task referenced in the question, I also need to do something analogous for a reverse-sorted array. Obviously this can be accomplished using the sorter arg, but it ends up being cleaner to just use gboffi's solution in this case. Either way, thanks a ton!